# Why coded UI test raises "Cannot perform 'Drag' on the control" ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I record the drag operation on a standard MFC application. Before recording, I make a dockable pane (like class view, file view) floating. Then drag it with mouse and record it by coded UI builder. Below is code generated by coded UI builder. I am using VS 2012 Ultimate version.

```
    public void RecordedMethod29()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinClient uIClassViewClient = this.UIClassViewWindow.UIClassViewClient;
        #endregion

        // Move 'Class View' client
        //System parameter 'Show window contents while dragging' is not set.This could lead to incorrect recording of drag actions.
        Mouse.StartDragging(uIClassViewClient, new Point(120, -11));
        Mouse.StopDragging(uIClassViewClient, 19, -17);
    }
```

However, during replaying, VS raises below error. I think the key information is "Cannot perform 'Drag' on the control". Does anyone meet such issue? I don't believe coded UI test cannot record/replay the drag operation on a floating window. BTW, I also enable Windows setting "Show window contents while dragging" mentioned in the comments of code: "System parameter 'Show window contents while dragging' is not set.This could lead to incorrect recording of drag actions."
But error still happens.

Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MFCApplication3\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITest1.cs : line 27
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:01.2473599

Result Message: 
Test method CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform 'Drag' on the control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
Name:  'Class View'
ControlType:  'Client'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 对 COM 组件的调用返回了错误 HRESULT E_FAIL。
Result StackTrace:
在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.EnsureVisible(Int32 nEnsureVisibleFlag, Int32 x, Int32 y, IScrollerCallback pScrollerCallback, Int32 nScrollFlag, Int32 nMaximumContainers)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.StartDragging(Point relativeCoordinate, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, IPlaybackContext context)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, String actionName, UITestControl uiControl)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.StartDragging(Point relativeCoordinate, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestActionExecutorCore.StartDragging(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.StartDraggingImplementation(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__14()
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.StartDragging(UITestControl control, Point relativeCoordinate, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys)
   在 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.StartDragging(UITestControl control, Point relativeCoordinate)
   在 CodedUITestProject1.UIMap.RecordedMethod30() 位置 c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MFCApplication3\CodedUITestProject1\UIMap.Designer.cs:行号 657
   在 CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() 位置 c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MFCApplication3\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITest1.cs:行号 29

Comment: I am having the same problem but I don't get an error, the drag simply doesn't work unless I manually wiggle the mouse. Mouse.Move in code does not work for some reason! It's a good question which I have seen in a few places but no good answers.

Comment: Yes, it seems Microsoft doesn't fully support UI controls in MFC feature pack like Dockable pane.